# Swift: fastest way to copy buffers of UInt32

Tags: swift, pointers, memcpy, unsafemutablepointer

I've got code that has two `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>`s, and need to *selectively* copy from one buffer to the other, as fast as possible. There is some logic that decides wether the element at a particular index/address is copied or not, so unfortunately I can't just `memcpy()` the whole lot.

What is the quickest way to do a per-element buffer copy in Swift?

For the purpose of simplicity, I've removed the per-element logic in the examples below.

This is **slow** (56ms):

```
for i in 0..<size {
    if ... {
        dest[i] = source[i]
    }
}
```

This is much faster (18ms), but I'd like to go quicker:

```
var srcPtr = source.baseAddress
var dstPtr = dest.baseAddress

for i in 0..<size {
    if ... {
        srcPtr.pointee = dstPtr.pointee
        srcPtr = srcPtr.advance(by: 1)
        dstPtr = dstPtr.advance(by: 1)
    }
}
```

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Are you testing with compiler optimizations enabled (`-O`)?

Comment: I'm currently running in regular debug, no optimisations.

Comment: Unfortunately, non-optimized builds often don't tell you very much about the performance in a release build. Swift relies very heavily on optimizations such as generics specialization to achieve a C-like level of performance. It may well be that your first example is as fast or faster than the second in an optimized build.

Comment: also enabling wholemodule optimization increase speed